# too many arguments to function call - ninja error

Tags: android, ninja

Keep getting stuck at this error while trying to compile LineageOS
Does anyone know what this is / how to resolve this

```
1 warning generated.
[ 64% 33226/51897] target  C++: netd <= system/netd/server/CommandListener.cpp
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(PWD=/proc/self/cwd  prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++ -I device/sony/suzuran/include -I hardware/libhardware_legacy/include/hardware_legacy -I bionic/libc/dns/include -I external/mdnsresponder/mDNSShared -I system/netd/include -I /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/aidl-generated/include -I system/netd/server -I /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates -I /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/gen/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates -I libnativehelper/include/nativehelper \$(cat /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/import_includes) -isystem system/core/include -isystem system/media/audio/include -isystem hardware/libhardware/include -isystem hardware/libhardware_legacy/include -isystem libnativehelper/include -isystem frameworks/native/include -isystem frameworks/native/opengl/include -isystem frameworks/av/include -isystem frameworks/base/include -isystem hardware/ril-caf/include -isystem /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/include -isystem bionic/libc/arch-arm64/include -isystem bionic/libc/include -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/common -isystem bionic/libc/kernel/uapi/asm-arm64 -isystem bionic/libm/include -isystem bionic/libm/include/arm64 -c    -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funwind-tables -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-short-enums -no-canonical-prefixes -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DQCOM_HARDWARE -DQCOM_BSP -DQTI_BSP -DHAS_EXTRA_FLAC_METADATA -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=date-time -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fcolor-diagnostics -nostdlibinc     -target aarch64-linux-android -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin    -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DQCOM_HARDWARE -DQCOM_BSP -DQTI_BSP -DHAS_EXTRA_FLAC_METADATA -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -nostdlibinc     -fno-rtti -fpie -D_USING_LIBCXX -std=gnu++14 -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror  -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast  -Werror=address-of-temporary -Werror=null-dereference -Werror=return-type    -MD -MF /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/CommandListener.d -o /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/CommandListener.o system/netd/server/CommandListener.cpp ) && (cp /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/CommandListener.d /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/CommandListener.P; sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\\\\$//' -e '/^\$/ d' -e 's/\$/ :/' < /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/CommandListener.d >> /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/CommandListener.P; rm -f /home/zane/Lineage/out/target/product/suzuran/obj/EXECUTABLES/netd_intermediates/CommandListener.d )"
system/netd/server/CommandListener.cpp:804:51: error: too many arguments to function call, expected at most single argument 'global_ctrl_iface', have 2 arguments
        rc = gCtls->softapCtrl.startSoftap(false, cli);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~        ^~~
system/netd/server/SoftapController.h:41:5: note: 'startSoftap' declared here
    int startSoftap(bool global_ctrl_iface = false);
    ^
1 error generated.
[ 64% 33226/51897] target  C++: netd <= system/netd/server/BandwidthController.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/zane/Lineage'

#### make failed to build some targets (01:25:28 (hh:mm:ss)) ####
```

Here are the githubs I am using to make this: [LineageOS](https://github.com/LineageOS) Merged Sumire(Lineage) files with [Suzuran](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/device-sony-suzuran)

Comment: Is this from your own code or a library?

Comment: Library - Just edited OP with the GitHubs I am using. 
The Suzuran tree I had to merge with the sumire tree from the LineageOS  GitHub. 

I am making Lineage using StockBlobs from my device (If that helps in any way)